# WPF filter Items Observable Collection without deleting views

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, graphics, itemscontrol

I've an ItemsControl and I'm binding the ItemsSource to an Observable Collection of ViewModels. This is how I'm binding to it...

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsvColl}" Background="Black">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Layout:CustomPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ItemViewModel}">
        <Border BorderThickness="3">
            <DMC:UserControl 
                Center="{Binding DataContext.Center, Source={x:Reference Name=SummaryView}}"
                ID="{Binding ID}" 
                ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The UserControl is sorta like an image control. When the user double clicks on a usercontrol, I'm removing all items from the observable collection except the one which was double clicked. This will make the clicked UserControl maximize. When the user double clicks again, I'm readding all the removed ViewModels to the observable collection.

Now when I remove ViewModels from the Observable collection, all the other usercontrols are deleted. When I'm adding the viewmodels again, I gets rerendered. Is there any way to not remove Views but hide them and display the selected usercontrol and bring them back when needed.

I tried collapsing the usercontrols but it just leaves empty spaces in place. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about adding a "SelectedViewModel" property, populate it when double clicking. Then use the "SelectedViewModel" instance in either a modal dialog, or after navigating to another page or within a hidden view container (making the Items panel hidden)?

Comment: _I tried collapsing the usercontrols but it just leaves empty spaces in place. Is there a way to do this?_ Are you sure ? `Visibility="Hidden"` yes, but `Visibility="Collapsed"` should not leave any empty space

Comment: @NawedNabiZada It does leave empty spaces. I think that is because of the CustomPanel which will allocate equal space to all items.

Comment: @ChrisBD are you suggesting to hide the Itemscontrol itself and put something on top of that ?

Comment: Yes. Depending on how you want it to look you may find it cleaner and quicker to open a modal page and display your selected item on that. The main thing is to not repopulate your ObservableCollection as each new entry will trigger a screen refresh.

Comment: Did you know that `ItemsControl` does not support UI virtualization to improve rendering performance? `ListBox` is an advanced `ItemsControl` in that it provides a `ScrollViewer` and UI virtualization by default. You should consider to replace `ItemsControl` with a `ListBox`. `ListBox` should also simplify your code because `ListBox` in addition exposes a `SelectedItem` property which you could use to filter the collection view. Filtering using the collection view does not modify the underlying collection. The type hierarchy is `ItemsControl`<--`Selector`<--`ListBox`.

Comment: For example: `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollection(myObservableCollection).Filter = item => item == myListBox.SelectedItem;`. This will only show the selected item (UserControl)  without modifying the original collection. WPF binding always works on collection views rather than on the real collection. That's why this works.